# Restrict cefsharp js binded objects to whitelisted domains

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have a CEFSharp browser implementation where I have few C# objects binded to CEF browser using `JavascriptObjectRepository`. Issue is when user tries to navigate across pages, he can end up on unintended page which can exploit this exposed object. I need to restrict these objects to specific domain(s). Is there a right way to achieve this?

**Note:** I've see [MethodInterceptor](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_ModelBinding_IMethodInterceptor_Intercept.htm) that can be added in binding option, but it doesn't give out url as a parameter.

Comment: How are you binding your object? You should only call CefSharp.BindObjectAsync for domains you control.

Comment: I'm using [JavascriptObjectRepository.Register](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IJavascriptObjectRepository_Register.htm) and binding it from C# side when browser is getting launched.

Comment: There's currently no whitelist option as part of the framework,  it is something that could be added without too much effort,. You should be able to implement this in your own application quite easily.

Comment: Thanks, @amaitland. I initially tried the same by trying to access the browser.Address in Method Interceptor which was inaccessible, which made me think it might not be the right idea. I now tried to use the AddressChangedEvent to always read the latest address and store it in MethodInterceptor which is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Got stuck on this for a while but found the answer. I had to implement MethodInterceptor for tracking the object usage across sites. Since the method interceptor didn't have a URL parameter, I had to explicitly subscribe to address the change event in the ChromiumWebBrowser instance.

1. Binding -

   ```
   BindingOptions bindingOptions = new BindingOptions();
   bindingOptions.MethodInterceptor = new CefJSObjectInterceptor(browser);    
   browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register(jsName, jsObj, true, bindingOptions); // Note: skipped LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled check
   ```
2. Method interceptor implementation -

   ```
    internal class CefJSObjectInterceptor : IMethodInterceptor
    {
        string currentAddress;
        public CefJSObjectInterceptor(ChromiumWebBrowser browser)
        {
            browser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;
        }

        private void Browser_AddressChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            currentAddress = e.NewValue.ToString();
        }

        public object Intercept(Func<object[], object> method, object[] parameters, string methodName)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(currentAddress);
            string url = uri.Host.ToString();
            if (isAcceptableURL(url))
            {
                object result = method(parameters);
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        }

        bool isAcceptableURL(string url)
        {
            HashSet<string> validURLs = new HashSet<string> { "google.com", "microsoft.com", "127.0.0.1" };
            foreach (var validURL in validURLs)
            {
                if (url.EndsWith(validURL))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Are you using legacy JavaScript Binding? If not then only calling BindObjectAsync in JavaScript for pages in your whitelist. If you are using legacy binding then I'd consider switching. Your solution will have overhead that would be best avoided. If you stick with what you have considered improving isAcceptableURL, creating a new hashset for every call is relatively expensive.

Comment: Agreed on the HashSet part, just added it as quick code. We were using legacy JS binding for the application and we have planned to move from legacy binding in time.